# Access forbiden when downloading from private registry via helm chart, but not via simple pod

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I am trying to deploy bitnami moodle chart with custom image hosted on gitlab. When I use the registry in pod the image gets downloaded. However, when used in the chart, it gives the error below with access forbiden. Tested on minikube, and private cluster.

```
*Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/<repo>/01976966/container/external/moodle:3.11.4-debian-10-r0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Er ││ ror response from daemon: Head "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/<repo>/01976966/container/external/moodle/manifests/3.11.4-debian-10-r0": denied: access forbidden*
```

This settings are used in parent chart values.yaml:

```
image:
      registry: registry.gitlab.com
      repository: <repo>/01976966/container/external/moodle
      tag: 3.11.4-debian-10-r0
      pullPolicy: Always
      pullSecrets:
        - name: <secret-name>
```

Base chart in question: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/moodle/

Comment: You have `- name:` in your `pullSecrets:` but [the values uses just the Secret name](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/moodle/values.yaml#L65) [and here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/common/templates/_images.tpl#L44); but, ultimately the answer is "did it end up generating the `PodSpec` you expected," and start debugging from there

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you! I wouldn't spot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```yaml
image:
  pullSecrets:
  - name: the-secret-name
```

but [their values uses just the Secret name](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/moodle/values.yaml#L65) and [as seen here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/common/templates/_images.tpl#L44)

You'll want to just make a list of the secret names:

```yaml
image:
  pullSecrets:
  - the-secret-name
```